# Is "holn" a contraction for abholen?

Tags: meaning

I've been following Ralph Ruthe, both because he's funny and to practice my German.

This comic has a beaver surprising a porcupine who has, ahem ... "occupied" ... the beaver's home during the beaver's short absence.  The beaver says, "Ich war nur kurz Ketchup holn!"

I get that "holn" has to be "to get" or "to fetch", but the word itself isn't in dict.cc, the dictionary I use.

Is "holn" a contraction for abholen? Or is this a special usage?

https://twitter.com/ralphruthe/status/1034755606199054336

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *holn* is a colloquial contraction of *holen*.

Just the way to omit the e in the written word is unusual, but in spoken language, this is a normal variation of pronunciation of many words. This has to do with how to pronounce ...

### Reduktionssilben

When talking about stressing of syllables, German has three types of syllables:

- betonte Silben (stressed syllables)
- unbetonte Silben (unstressed syllables)
- Reduktionssilben (reduction syllables)

Reduction syllables can be seen as a subset of unstressed syllables, i.e they are even less stressed than normal unstressed syllables, and they are characterized by there properties:

- Only the last syllable of a word can be a *Reduktionssilbe*.
- When written, a *Reduktionssilbe* always contains the letter **e**.

When spoken, the vowel of a *Reduktionssilbe* is either:

1. [ə] (mid central vowel, aka schwa) like in *Torte, dieses, Rahmen* ([ˈtɔʁt**ə**], [ˈdiːz**ə**s], [ˈʀaːm**ə**n])
2. [ɐ] (near-open central vowel) like in *Bauer, Federn, hundert* ([ˈbaʊ̯**ɐ**], [ˈfeːd**ɐ**n], [ˈhʊnd**ɐ**t])
3. missing, i.e. a sonor consonant (often *n* or *l*) is the core of the syllable like in *Leben, Regel, jodeln* ([ˈleːbn̩], [ˈʀeːɡl̩], [ˈjoːdl̩n])

German vocabulary is full of words, where the last syllable is slowly shifting from type 1 to type 3 within a longer period of time, or exists in both forms. Most of them are words ending in *-en* like:

> - Regen [ˈʀeːɡən], [ˈʀeːɡn̩]
> - sollen [ˈzɔlən], [ˈzɔl̩n]
> - laufen [ˈlaʊ̯fən], [ˈlaʊ̯fn̩]

And of course also

> - holen [ˈhoːlən], [ˈhoːl̩n]

Sometimes an author explicitly wants to mark, that such a word should be pronounced without a vowel in the last syllable (for example in poems where pronunciation can be important for rhythm and rhymes). The standard way to do this is to use an apostrophe (*soll’n, hol’n*), But some authors prefer not to this, and then you get *Regn, solln, laufn, holn*. But non of these spellings is standard German spelling. When a student writes this, his teacher would mark it as an error.

Answer (score 6):

It's a contracted form of *holen*, which is in [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=holen). *Abholen* in turn is derived from *holen*.

Answer (score 3):

Nein, *holn* ist einfach nur *holen*, sprich, das E wird verschluckt.

Der Unterschied zu abholen ist, dass bei diesem etwas bereitgestellt, bereitgelegt wird.

Vorbestellte Kinokarten kann man abholen. Dagegen holt man sich im Backladen Brötchen.